# These two strings are supposed to be the same length but when printed they do not appear that way

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ascii-art

```
a="|:watch:️ :mobile phone: :mobile phone with arrow: :laptop: :keyboard: :desktop computer:        |"
b="|:printer: :computer mouse: :trackball: :joystick: :clamp: :computer disk: :floppy disk: :optical|"
```

both of these strings should be 98 characters, but when printing with a monospaced font (in my terminal) it shows `b` as being longer

[terminal output when printing length of each string followed by string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dP9L.png)

This shouldn't be an issue but I'm trying to draw a box around some text and this glitch causes the table to be misaligned. Is it possible that the font is not properly monospaced? I am using VS Code for the Web.

Thank you kindly for your time.

Comment: if you would use VSC >= 1.70 you would see it flags a Unicode character as invisible

Comment: @rioV8 you are right, just noticed the orange box around it. Thanks!

Comment: how did you type these 2 strings, how do you type `U+fe0f`

Comment: copied it from the output of my program which pulls data from an API, sometimes output has these unprintable characters it seems @rioV8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was guessing that one of the chars in `a` is strange. We can see this if we print them:

```py
In [4]: for i, char in enumerate(a):
   ...:     print((i, char))
   ...:
(0, '|')
(1, ':')
(2, 'w')
(3, 'a')
(4, 't')
(5, 'c')
(6, 'h')
(7, ':')
(8, '️')
(9, ' ')
(10, ':')
(11, 'm')
(12, 'o')
(13, 'b')
(14, 'i')
(15, 'l')
(16, 'e')
(17, ' ')
(18, 'p')
(19, 'h')
(20, 'o')
(21, 'n')
(22, 'e')
(23, ':')
(24, ' ')
(25, ':')
(26, 'm')
(27, 'o')
(28, 'b')
(29, 'i')
(30, 'l')
(31, 'e')
(32, ' ')
(33, 'p')
(34, 'h')
(35, 'o')
(36, 'n')
(37, 'e')
(38, ' ')
(39, 'w')
(40, 'i')
(41, 't')
(42, 'h')
(43, ' ')
(44, 'a')
(45, 'r')
(46, 'r')
(47, 'o')
(48, 'w')
(49, ':')
(50, ' ')
(51, ':')
(52, 'l')
(53, 'a')
(54, 'p')
(55, 't')
(56, 'o')
(57, 'p')
(58, ':')
(59, ' ')
(60, ':')
(61, 'k')
(62, 'e')
(63, 'y')
(64, 'b')
(65, 'o')
(66, 'a')
(67, 'r')
(68, 'd')
(69, ':')
(70, ' ')
(71, ':')
(72, 'd')
(73, 'e')
(74, 's')
(75, 'k')
(76, 't')
(77, 'o')
(78, 'p')
(79, ' ')
(80, 'c')
(81, 'o')
(82, 'm')
(83, 'p')
(84, 'u')
(85, 't')
(86, 'e')
(87, 'r')
(88, ':')
(89, ' ')
(90, ' ')
(91, ' ')
(92, ' ')
(93, ' ')
(94, ' ')
(95, ' ')
(96, ' ')
(97, '|')
```

So we can see that at index `8` there is some kind of "zero width" character.

We can inspect the char to find its codepoint:

```py
In [5]: ord(a[8])
Out[5]: 65039
```

This appears to be Unicode "VARIATION SELECTOR-16": https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe0f/index.htm

Some kind of modifying character that has no printable representation of its own.

Comment: Thanks! Successfully filtered out the characters not in `string.printable`

Comment: Small issue with filtering characters using `string.printable` is special characters that are printable will not be printed (filtering out more than just the zero-width characters)

Do you know how I can easily identify zero-width characters in python?

Comment: Try this package: https://github.com/jquast/wcwidth if it's for purpose of drawing a box then you only need to measure the printable length accurately (seems to work!) ... you could also measure each char and filter out any zero-width ones, but that would probably break some languages which rely on modifier chars legitimately

Comment: Ended up using https://github.com/jquast/blessed/ since it offers a text wrapper and supports ANSI escape codes. Wouldn't have found it if I hadn't searched "wcwidth" and "wrap"

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, some characters are printed different than wcwidth expects (ex an emoji that cannot be rendered is printed as a question mark, but wcwidth expects it to be printed to a width of 2)

Ended up getting column position of the cursor using blessed library to figure out where to draw the box. Bit slow but works! Hopefully also means more consistent results with different machines (which cannot print some characters)

Answer (score 0):

try to add one profit to a or copy this and try...

```
a="|:watch:️ :mobile phone: :mobile phone with arrow: :laptop: :keyboard: :desktop computer:         |"
b="|:printer: :computer mouse: :trackball: :joystick: :clamp: :computer disk: :floppy disk: :optical|"
```

Comment: Thank you Aviya! Turns out thie issue was a non-printable character.

Comment: Not clear what "one profit" means